# How to get the buffer data of my image in <img>?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image tag in my HTML code with `src` containing the path to a local image.

```
<img alt="abc" src="./images/abc.png" />
```

Upon clicking the image, I want to call a JavaScript method that will return the buffer data of the image.

Example buffer:

```
(23234)[234,345,786]
```

How is it done in pure JavaScript?

Comment: Have you thought about creating a canvas element and then converting it to toDataUrl()?

Comment: Do you mean the Base 64 encoding of the image?

Answer (score 0):

You can not read pixels from an image, but you can draw an image to a canvas, and use `getImageData` to extract an array of the RGBA pixel data. Then it is possible to get color under the mouse cursor.
Notes about the example below:

- the image is tiny because `getImageData` has cross-origin protection, and as uploading images for examples does not seem to be possible, the image is encoded in a data URI
- however data URI-s also have cross-origin issues in certain browsers, like IE (it will not with IE as far as I remember). I tested the code with Chrome, so that works for sure, and I think it should work with Firefox too
- none of these matters with real life code, so if you get this code out from here, and just write `<img src="something.jpg" ...` (so hosted locally), it can be a large image and it will work with IE too
- there is some race condition here, sometimes I get messages about missing `imgready` function, so StackOverflow may load the HTML first and inject the scripts later. If you see that message, run the snippet again. With more "traditional" code order (scripts located in `head`) it could not happen

```js
var imgdata;

function imgready(){
  var img=document.getElementById("you");
  var cnv=document.createElement("canvas");
  var w=cnv.width=img.width;
  var h=cnv.height=img.height;
  var ctx=cnv.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  imgdata=ctx.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
}

function mmove(event){
  if(!imgdata)return;
  var x=event.clientX-event.target.offsetLeft;
  var y=event.clientY-event.target.offsetTop;
  var offset=(x+y*imgdata.width)*4;
  var r=imgdata.data[offset];
  var g=imgdata.data[offset+1];
  var b=imgdata.data[offset+2];
  document.getElementById("logdiv").innerText=x+","+y+" ("+offset+"): r="+r+" g="+g+" b="+b;
  var cnv=document.getElementById("colorcnv");
  var ctx=cnv.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cnv.width,cnv.height);
  ctx.fillStyle="rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(10,10,10,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" id="you" onload="imgready()" onmousemove="mmove(event)">
<canvas id="colorcnv" width="20" height="20"></canvas><br>
<div id="logdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified version of tevemadar's answer that might be usefull:

```
function imgToBuffer(e){
  let cnv=document.createElement("canvas"), w=cnv.width=e.width, h=cnv.height=e.height, ctx=cnv.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(e,0,0);
  return getImageData(0,0,w,h)
}
```

This function simply draws the image element to canvas and returns the image buffer. No extra HTML needed.

To get the ArrayBuffer out of it, use

```
imgToBuffer(el).data.buffer
```